# Magento 1.9 : Equivalent of 'AND' in Magento ORM

Tags: magento

I want to generate the following the query :

```
SELECT column1,column2 FROM table_name WHERE col3 = 'x' and col8 = 'y'
```

I've tried

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96930/addfilter-vs-addfieldtofilter

Where I did this :

```
$items= Mage::getModel('orderupdate/orderaftermanufacture')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter(array('order_increment_id','status'), array($this->order,0))->addFieldToSelect('item_id');
```

But this results in 'OR'. I want 'AND'.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem as :

```
    $items= Mage::getModel('orderupdate/orderaftermanufacture')->getCollection()->addFilter('order_increment_id',$this->order)->addFilter('status',0)->addFieldToSelect('item_id');
```

Which calls

```
/**
 * Add collection filter
 *s
 * @param string $field
 * @param string $value
 * @param string $type and|or|string
 */
public function addFilter($field, $value, $type = 'and')
```

Where parameter `$type` determines `and` or `or`